# How to create properties for Derived React components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, oop

I am creating a class/component library that is helping me to learn React. I am programming it in Typescript.

I am having difficulty making real objects derived from parent components that can add new properties.

When I speak of parent components here, I am not talking about parents that contain child components. Adding new properties to these components is well documented throughout the Internet (with several examples provided in Stack Overflow posts). This is about base classes that have properties and derived classes that have the base properties plus additional properties that can be set in the same way as the properties set in the base class.

For example: it is possible using Typescript to create a component that uses what amounts to a base component in the manner shown below:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import BasePage from "./BasePage";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </header>
      <BasePage firstLine="The first line" secondLine="A second line" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The `<BasePage>` tag shown in the above code can be implemented as follows:

```
import React from 'react';

interface IProps {
    firstLine: string;
    secondLine: string;
}

class BasePage extends React.Component<IProps> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.props.firstLine}</p>
                <p>{this.props.secondLine}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default BasePage;
```

Problems arise when I need to create a component derived from another component (in this case BasePage) that has its own additional properties. For example, what I would like to be able to do is derive a component from BasePage that has, *in addition to* the properties provided for BasePage, a property that provides an H1 header to the page:

```
import React from 'react';
import BasePage from "./BasePage";

class DerivedPage extends BasePage {
    render(): React.JSX.Element {
        const pageinfo = super.render();

        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Header needs to be a property</h1>
                {pageinfo}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default DerivedPage;
```

The idea would be to be able to use the `<DerivedPage>` tag in the following manner:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import BasePage from "./BasePage";
import DerivedPage from "./DerivedPage";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </header>
      <BasePage firstLine="The first line" secondLine="A second line" />
      /*
       * The desired tag
      <DerivedPage firstLine="This has lines like the base page"
                   secondLine="But I can't pass a property for the header." 
                   h1Header="Some Title" />
       */
      /*
       * The actual tag
       */
      <DerivedPage firstLine="This has lines like the base page"
                   secondLine="But I can't pass a property for the header." />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Unfortunately, while there appear to be several ways of declaring properties in a derived component that can be used by that component, I have been unable to find any examples of how to make a derived component's unique property settable from the containing component in the way shown in the above code.

Of course, one way to make the derived component's property available would be to add it as an optional (or a property with a default value) component in the IProp interface, but that makes it available to the base component (in the process violating object orientation) which has no use for it. This would be a particularly bad implementation if any of the properties I am using in the derived component are function properties.

So my question is: is there a way to add properties that are unique to a derived component so that they can be set in the same manner as the properties of the base component that it is derived from? If so, how is this done?